# Return top # of rows from left table while returning all rows from right joined tables

Tags: sql, vbscript

I'm trying to limit the number or orders returned but not the total of rows. I would like to select the top 15 rows from the orders table but return all related rows from the joined tables.

The statement below returns a total of 15 rows total rather than all data from the first 15 orders. Your help is appreciated.

```
sSQL2 = "SELECT TOP 15 orders.oID
    , orders.oName
    , cartoptions.coCartOption
    , cart.cProdID
    , cartoptions.coCartID
    , cart.cProdName
    , cart.cQuantity
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN cart
    ON orders.oid = cart.corderid
LEFT JOIN cartoptions
    ON cart.cid = cartoptions.cocartid
WHERE orders.oComplete = 1
    AND (
        cartoptions.coOptGroup = 'Logo Style'
        AND cartoptions.coCartOption = 'KGM'
        )
ORDER BY orders.oDate"
```

Comment: So you want to return all data from the first 15 orders and not just the first 15 rows??

Comment: Also, how do you decide the which are the first 15 orders? What column do you use to make that distinction? Is it Orders.oDate?

Comment: Correct, I want all data from the first 15 orders but my query is only returning 15 rows instead when there are multiple items per order and I would like a row for each item but need to make certain all rows pertaining to those 15 orders are included in the results. I was just using TOP 15 and order by oDate. It really doesn't matter which 15 orders but it makes sense to take the ones created first.

Comment: Take a look at the suggestion/answer below. Despite it being a bit sloppy (oops), the point is to just pull the 15 records in with a subquery and use it as another source in your join. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, and untested, but this might work:

```
sSQL2 = "SELECT orderList.oName
              , cartoptions.coCartOption
              , cart.cProdID
              , cartoptions.coCartID
              , cart.cProdName
             , cart.cQuantity
           from (Select TOP 15 oID
                             , oName
                  from orders
                  order by oDate desc) orderList

LEFT JOIN cart
    ON orderList.oid = cart.corderid
LEFT JOIN cartoptions
    ON cart.cid = cartoptions.cocartid
WHERE orderList.oComplete = 1
    AND (
        cartoptions.coOptGroup = 'Logo Style'
        AND cartoptions.coCartOption = 'KGM'
        )"
```

Comment: I would suggest that you add the `order by` clause to the subquery.

Comment: and a `"` would be useful at the end as well.

Comment: LOL Thanks @Rich, absolutely :)

Comment: I'm getting Invalid column name 'oID'. It doesn't look like you've referenced the orders table so how would the select know where to get the oID, etc? Also, I take it that the second comma shouldn't be there?

Comment: Inadvertent omission on the FROM clause of the subquery. My apologies, @user3461377. Extra comma removed. Might give it another try :)

Comment: Thanks, no errors but the new query also returns no data. Here is the actual updated query if it helps any. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: sSQL2 = "SELECT orderList.ordName, cartoptions.coCartOption, cart.cartProdID, cartoptions.coCartID, cart.cartProdName, cart.cartQuantity from (Select TOP 15 ordID, ordName, ordComplete, ordExported, ordStore from orders order by ordDate) orderList LEFT JOIN cart ON orderList.ordid = cart.cartorderid LEFT JOIN cartoptions ON cart.cartid = cartoptions.cocartid WHERE orderList.ordComplete = 1 AND orderList.ordExported = 0 AND orderList.ordStore = 000000 AND (cartoptions.coOptGroup = 'Logo Style' AND cartoptions.coCartOption = 'KGM')"

Comment: @user3461377 In looking at this and the other answer, they're essentially mirror-images of each other, and both are returning no data. Reallly makes me suspicious of a data problem. Do me a favor and remove your WHERE clause and re-run the query, and see if there are still no records. Or it could be that the top 15 records (oldest) may not join up to your other tables - try also adding DESC to the end of the subquery's ORDER BY clause (i'll amend the answer)

Comment: Removing the WHERE clause did return data, I had to add the other fields and then DESC fixed it. However, it's not quite right. If I use TOP 10, it returns 2 rows, TOP 15 returns 5, TOP 25 returns 8 rows. Odd.

Comment: That means that your join condition is creating gaps on your "right-hand" side where there are no records that match across your join conditions. You could do a select out of each table where the field in the join condition doesn't exist, or temporarily change the query to left *outer* joins and check for nulls on the right-hand sides of the relationship to discover the "holes" in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
sSQL2 = "SELECT orders.oID
    , orders.oName
    , cartoptions.coCartOption
    , cart.cProdID
    , cartoptions.coCartID
    , cart.cProdName
    , cart.cQuantity
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 15 *         
    FROM orders
    Where oid is not null
    )orders
LEFT JOIN cart
    ON orders.oid = cart.corderid
LEFT JOIN cartoptions
    ON cart.cid = cartoptions.cocartid
WHERE orders.oComplete = 1
    AND (
        cartoptions.coOptGroup = 'Logo Style'
        AND cartoptions.coCartOption = 'KGM'
        )"
```

Comment: I get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH' using this.

Comment: Thanks. No errors, but the query returns no results when it should.

Comment: I am guessing that your Orders table has quite a few entries with Null Oid... Try the updated query.

Comment: Nope. oID is primary and no nulls allowed. I did however search for nulls and = '' just in case. Same results unless I remove the where clause. Again, thanks.